# andengine particle fade in and fade out without transparent

Tags: android, andengine, particle-system

Is it possible to fade in/fade out particles without using GLE2 blend function?
If using GLE2 blend function, I can't use BLACK particle and they are almost invisible in light background.

```
particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new BlendFunctionParticleInitializer<Sprite>(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE));
```

I tried using other parameter like GLES20.ALPHA, It works great only if the background is an image, on colored background (this.mScene.setBackground(xxxxx)), it shows a black background in the particle where is supposed to be transparent.

[image][image]

Thank you!